# Namespace inheritance unexpected behaviour

Tags: inheritance, namespaces, mako, function

**a.mako**

```
<%def file="one()">
    ${ two() }
</%def>

<%def file="two()">
    two
</%def>
```

**b.mako**

```
<%inherit file="a.mako" />
<%def file="two()">
    overriden two
</%def>
```

and I want to use **b.mako** as an namespace like

```
<%namespace name="test_namespace" file="b.mako" />
${ one() }
```

I'm expecting `overriden two` but it's still `two`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The trick was in `self`.

I should write

```
<%def file="one()">
    ${ self.two() }
</%def>
```

It is partially covered by documentation indeed

http://docs.makotemplates.org/en/latest/inheritance.html#but-what-about-defs

*Where above, the title() def, because it’s a def within a def, is not part of the template’s exported namespace and will not be part of self. If the inherited template did define its own title def at the top level, it would be called, but the “default title” above is not present at all on self no matter what.*